# How to fix the error with importing files in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When I want to import/export data to a table in my database appears a issue.

> "Utility not found. C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\bin\psql.exe' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog".

[image: error]

But the thing is that I put the correct path to my files where pgAdmin is installed, but idk why there is no necessary files how you see in the error.

Comment: Does the path you put there match the one in the error message?  In my hands, the correct location is just `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to `Preference > paths > Binary Paths > PostgreSQL Binary Path > PostgreSQL 14`
- set path as `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\`
- then `save > Refresh your Table`
- and now try importing

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work after that, validate the folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).